# Android Camera2 video aspect ratio

Tags: android, aspect-ratio, android-camera2

I don't believe the following as been explicitly answered:
Using the Camera2 API, is it possible to record outside a native device resolution (say, 1:1) *without the use of post-processing such as ffmpeg*?

Comment: It is possible, see e.g. https://blog.lemberg.co.uk/surface-view-video-cropping. Maybe, SCALER_CROP_REGION can help you do it easier.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a lot of detail to explain exactly what resolution you want to use, but sounds like you want to record in an aspect ratio/resolution that doesn't match one of the supported aspect ratios/resolutions from the device's camera.

You can always send the image data to the GPU, do whatever cropping/scaling you want there, and then send it on to a video encoder.

Generally, that'd involve:

1. Setting up an EGL context
2. Creating a render target in EGL, and getting an Android Surface for it
3. Creating a SurfaceTexture to send texture data to EGL
4. Connect EGL input SurfaceTexture to the camera (by first creating a Surface from it, if using camera2)
5. Connect EGL output Surface to a MediaRecorder
6. Write shader code to process the incoming frames from camera, crop/scale/modify as needed, then render them to the output surface
7. Set up camera and media recorder, then start them both
8. In the SurfaceTexture onFrameAvailable, trigger your rendering code.

This is quite a bit of scaffolding to build, but should be rather efficient when done.